# Matching files of certain length that only contain digits?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I've been trying to match all file names in a directory that are 6 characters long and only contain digits. I've been banging my head trying to get it to work but with no luck. This is what I have:

```
for f in "$path"*
do
        if echo "$f" | tail -c 7 | grep "^[[:digit:]][:digit:]]*$"; then
                echo "$f is good"
        else
                echo "$f" | tail -c 7
        fi
done
```

Every time I run the script the else gets ran and I just  get the last 6 characters from each file in the directory. I don't want to have to cd into the directory to check the files so I thought taking the last 6 and checking would be a good idea (maybe not). I want to eventually redirect all files in $path that are 6 characters long and all digits. I just cant figure out how to match this. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried just `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`?

Comment: Since you do `tail -c 7`, you're not checking any of the characters *before* the last 6. You're testing whether the file ends with 6 digits, not whether it is *only* 6 digits.

Comment: The regex being used in the original post can be fixed to eliminate the call to tail. But as other comments and answers point out, there are other problems in the original code. Among other details, is "$path" guaranteed to end in a valid pathname separator (e.g. "/")?

Comment: no path is specified by the user as $2. So it depends on whether or not they provide the "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `basename` to get the filename part of a pathname, and test that:

```
for f in "$path"*
do
    base=$(basename "$f")
    case "$base" in
        [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
            echo "$f is good" ;;
        *) echo "$base" ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a one liner to just list the filenames:

`for f in "$path"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9];do echo ${f##*/};done`

if you want the full path just omit the `##*/`

Answer (score 1):

```
ls [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Or, if you simply want to edit your script:

```
for f in "$path"*
do
    if echo "$f" | tail -c 7 | grep "^[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]$"; then
            echo "$f is good"
    else
            echo "$f" | tail -c 7
    fi
done
```

Or, just use the regex pattern:

```
'^[[:digit:]]{6}$'
```

Comment: Your `for` loop has the same problem as the original code -- it's not checking the characters before the last 6.

Comment: From what I read, "match all file names in a directory that are 6 characters long and only contain digits," the file names are exactly six characters long and composed only of digits.

Comment: The way I read it, the filenames could be any length. He wants to select the ones that are exactly 6 characters long and only digits.

Comment: Edit the comment to use `$(...)` instead of backquotes.

Comment: Repost of comment edited after time available to edit seems to have expired or number of edits allowed has been exceeded: @Barmar But, I see your point about the full path name. Your suggestion to use basename will fix that. But he should also use: for f in ls "$path" OR cd $path ; for f in * OR for f in $(find $path -type f -print) BUT only if he does not mind searching possible subdirectories of $path in the last case...

Comment: @Barmar I agree, it seems obvious that file names can be any length, but selecting only files with six character names composed only of digits can be handled by a regex alone. In fact, the "for" line alone can do all the work with the widely portable version: for f in "$path"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]

Comment: That assumes `$path` is just the directory, not some prefix of the filename (his original code works with the latter).

Comment: @Barmar It does assume that. If "$path" ends in a file name prefix, the author would probably be better off discarding the prefix either before this point or using "basename" and then relying solely on a regex to select the specific files of interest. The problem is not fully specified, but the author of the question should have enough information at this point to fix at least this part of any script on which he or she is working.

Comment: Path can end in / or not. I have path set to $2 so it depends on if the user includes a slash at the end or not. Thanks for all the replies!